# How to merge two branches without specifying the local work copy path with SVN?

Tags: svn, merge

As I know, the usual steps to merge a branch into trunk:

1. checkout trunk/branch to local work copy dir

   svn co svn://server/proj/trunk

   svn co svn://server/proj/branch
2. merge the branch into trunk

   cd trunk  ## branch's local work copy dir

   svn up

   svn merge svn://server/proj/branch

   svn diff  ### now you can see what the branch changed

   svn ci -m "merge branch into trunk" ## merging into the svn repo

Now my situation:

1. I have no local work copy dir (in don't want to )-- it means I don't have to check out the trunk and branch to local disk.
2. Merge the branch into trunk only by given URL (svn://server/proj/trunk && svn://server/proj/branch) -- it means the merging occurs on the svn server.

I have read so much doc about svn operation, but still I have no idea how to meet the need.

i hope some guy could help to solve the problem.

Comment: It is just like asking: How to change a content of file in svn without a working copy?

Comment: is it different to my question? is there ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible.  You must have a working copy to merge in to--how else can conflicts be resolved, etc?

There is no way to do these merges on the server, since the server doesn't keep a "checked out" copy of the files anywhere.  The server is "just" a collection of files.

Answer (score 3):

In Subversion every merge operation will be done on the client side. The client solves also conflicts etc. Nothing is done on the server side (which is very good). If you like to merge you have to checkout the trunk or the branch whatever the target is.